# PHPmyadmin SQL Bug - Cant see all rows

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I think this is a mysql bug or something.

When I search for `select * from table` it shows me ( Showing rows 0 - 65 (66 total) ) it doesnt show the 66th row even after I click view all

has anyone ever experienced this?

[image]

Comment: Why do you think this is a MySQL bug, not an issue with phpMyAdmin?

Comment: 0 -65 is actually 66 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, 0 to 65 is already 66 rows (count from 0 to 65).

The 65th row is actually the 66th, as you start count from 0.

Comment: Glad I could help.